# Sub-menu navigation toggle bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, jquery-animate

I have a main navigation menu with a sub-menu that appears on hover, the problem I have is that on hovering on and off the menu sub-menu flickers between the slide and fade states provided by its function (menuHover) - I have a fiddle which is viewable [here](http://jsfiddle.net/q9crY/)

The function itself is:

```
    ///<summary>
    ///drop down menu navigation
    ///</summary>

    var menuHover = {

        //initialise our function
        init: function(){

            var menuItem = $(".navItem");                       

            //each menu item
            menuItem.each(function(){

                //checks to see if we have sub-navigation items             
                var $this = $(this),
                    hasSub = $this.children(".subNav"),
                    isSub = hasSub.length > 0;

                //toggle visibility on sub items when hovered               

                   if(isSub){              


                   $this.hover(
                   //on hover
                   function(){


                        hasSub.slideDown("fast");


                   }, 
                   // off hover
                   function(){


                        hasSub.fadeOut(350);


                   });                     


                   }


            }); 


        }
    };
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Stop using JS for menus! Use CSS instead!

The basics: http://www.seoconsultants.com/css/menus/tutorial/

Example I made(Copyrighted, do not just copy it): http://tinkerbin.com/W0iL32hh

Comment: No use, NEED the effects to work in ie7+ will bear this in mind for future projects though which don't have this requirement. Very nice - well done. J.

Comment: Most effects work already, though I would suggest you to use a background-image instead of a gradient.

Comment: If it bugs for you in the sense that it toggles off when you try to go to a submenu, move it a little bit higher and move your mouse faster to the submenu. IE7 does some tricks with the metrics.